# pop-up for 1 second

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the regular (or best) way to implement text+image message to user, while this "alert/pop-up" should appear only for 1 second (like message "You Won!" on Prize picture for limited period of time).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to show a floating message for a little bit of time and have it fade away, just make a label and a simple animation.  This example will show the message for 1 second then fade away over 0.3 seconds (and assumes ARC):

```
- (void)showMessage:(NSString*)message atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    const CGFloat fontSize = 24;  // Or whatever.

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize];  // Or whatever.
    label.text = message;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];  // Or whatever.
    [label sizeToFit];

    label.center = point;

    [self addSubview:label];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:1 options:0 animations:^{
        label.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        label.hidden = YES;
        [label removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Just add this as a method on your root view.

Comment: nice answer, will try it immedeately. (hard to understand what's wrong with my question - it's downvoted %))

Comment: Looking at the close reasons, it's not clear to me either.  Probably because you phrased it in a vague way.  Instead of broad, "what's the best way" try instead, "I want to do X.  How do I do that?"

Comment: your code gives and error - because of autorelease... (my project is under ARC)...

Comment: Oh, just remove the autorelease then.

Comment: Ya, it works. One stupid issue I should solve is "no visible @interface for ViewController declares the selector addSubView. What I missed? I put the declaration in ViewController.h - (void)showMessage:(NSString*)message atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

Comment: As written, you don't want to add this to your view controller, you want to add it a view.  Specifically a class you implement that derives from UIView.  UIViews have subviews and superviews.  If you add this to a UIViewController you want to change that line to be `[self.view addSubview:label]`, since your view controller should have a view property which is your root view for the current controller.

Comment: @jemmamaphone - INCREDIBLE! It worked. Should accept your answer definitely... but... it there any way to add a picture for this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I meant to add picture to popup (in fact, we have some come in the answer, however your example looks simplier

Comment: If you want to show an image instead of text, you can just replace the `UILabel` with a `UIImageView`.  Or you could replace it with a `UIView` that contains all sorts of crazy subviews, which is all that a `UIAlertView` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want user interaction, then go for a HUD.

Good implementations out there are [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) and [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

They are usually meant for progress, but you can use them for displaying transitory information to the user.

As an example, here's how you can easily display a 1 second message along with a custom image using `SVProgressHUD`:

```
[SVProgressHUD showImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"won-image"] status:@"You Won!"];
```

Comment: Let's say I want to show to the user "You Won!" message and dismiss it shortly after coming back to the last state screen without any changes. Simple reusable implementation.

Comment: As a side note, `SVProgressHUD` is far less configurable than `MBProgressHUD`, so for instance you cannot adjust the alert duration. On the other is much easier to use out of the box.

Comment: I am surprised - I thought that the implementation will be something like alert's method call with "duration" parameter...

Comment: It's a design choice, made by Sam Vermette. His components are very easy to use and very consistent, and the price to pay is customization. I tend to agree with his approach: I switched to `SVProgressHUD` because `MBProgressHUD` had become far too complicated to maintain for a simple project.

Comment: actually the duration is calculated according to the text length, so it's a pretty smart default. Check [this commit](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/commit/3904e821d0fec114d3abd1f323112d7e97e3d2f9) out