# How to flash text across the screen Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This post is regarding the last one I made about the tutorial. Anyways, I followed the tutorial, and the game looks pretty sweet. I added a few tweaks to make it more sensible. My only question is, how do I get text to flash across the screen (to say something like "Restarting Game") during the 5-second delay that occurs after a player loses the game? Thanks for your help!

Reference to the video (it's almost identical to the code I wrote, and I replaced the -void(replayGame) code with what commenter Anthony Mesada wrote):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4U03q1ZMY8&spfreload=10

Also, is there a way to speed up the space guys? They go so slow, and I feel the game is way too easy and it takes some of the fun away from it.

Comment: [How to show a UILabel for a brief period of time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18476198/74815).

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the video. To get the ending text to display, try creating a label in your viewDidLoad (with .hidden = YES) and then toggle the hidden parameter on/off. For example:

```
- (void)gameLoop {
    myLabel.hidden = NO;
}
```

And then when you restart the game:

```
- (void)gameLoop {
    myLabel.hidden = YES;
}
```

As far as the speed of the enemies, check out around 13:30 in the video. This is where he sets this value. He is creating a random integer that produces a 0, 1, or 2. Then if the integer is 0, he sets the enemy speed to .03. If the integer is 1, he set the enemy speed to .02. And if the integer is 2, he sets the enemy speed to .01. Try simply changing these speed values. For instance, instead of .03, .02, .01 try 10, 5, 2.